# Reusing the same webdriver for different tests, but not instantiating it every time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm making a project that runs tests on a web application using Selenium Webdriver. I need to be able to test different browsers in my CI Pipeline, so when I execute a test suite, I specify what browser should be used.

```
 mvn test -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/webdrivers/geckodriver" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/webdrivers/chromedriver" -DbrowserUnderTest="headless-firefox"
```

The tests use a `WebDriver` object to manipulate the browser, so, to make the code easy to maintain, I made it so that every test class inherits from a class called `BasicTest` where the `WebDriver driver` object is instantiated.

Also, to make test execution faster, I made it so that tests **reuse the same instance of the browser**, so, when a test ends, the next test uses the already-opened browser. That is why in the code of `BasicTest`, my `WebDriver` objects are defined as `public static` :

```java
    public static FirefoxOptions ff_opt_headless = new FirefoxOptions().setHeadless(true);
    public static ChromeOptions chrome_opt_headless = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--headless");

    public static WebDriver firefox_driver_headless = new FirefoxDriver(ff_opt_headless);
    public static WebDriver chrome_driver_headless = new ChromeDriver(chrome_opt_headless);

    public static WebDriver driver; 

    public BasicTest() throws Exception {
        String browserUnderTest = System.getProperty("browserUnderTest");
        switch (browserUnderTest) {
        case "headless-firefox":
            driver = firefox_driver_headless;
            break;
        case "headless-chrome":
            driver = chrome_driver_headless;
            break;
        }
    }
```

The problem that I have here is that `firefox_driver_headless` and `chrome_driver_headless` are instantiated every time, meaning that even if I specify Firefox for a test suite Chrome will also be opened uselessly. So I need to find a way to not instantiate the `firefox_driver_headless` and `chrome_driver_headless` objects when `BasicTest` is created.

If I keep it that way, when I add drivers for browsers that may not be available on every platform my tests can be run on, I will encounter issues. (ex: if my tests run on Linux, and I try to instantiate an `internet_explorer_webdriver` object, it will fail.)

I already tried to instantiate them in the switch case like below:

```java
public static WebDriver driver;
switch (browserUnderTest) {
        case "headless-firefox":
            WebDriver firefox_driver_headless = new FirefoxDriver(ff_opt_headless);
            driver = firefox_driver_headless;
            break;
        case "headless-chrome":
            WebDriver chrome_driver_headless = new ChromeDriver(chrome_opt_headless);
            driver = chrome_driver_headless;
            break;
        }
```

While this does not open Chrome when I launch my test, it also reopens Firefox for each test, which is not what I want: **I want the same instance of the browser to be reused for every test**.

So what is the solution here? Should I just give up trying to make it so that the same instance of the browser is reused for every test? I intended for the `TestSuite` would follow a logical order like a normal person navigating. (*ie, to test a "change avatar" feature, the `Login` test would be executed, then after that the `AccessProfile` test would be executed, then after that `ChangeAvatar`...*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your switch logic in a [static initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), so that it is only executed once when the `BasicTest` class is loaded

```java
static {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Clean and efficient structure